# FQL: Unable to read data from insights table

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I am trying to access our application's insight data with the following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?format=json&access_token=<removed>&q=
 SELECT object_id, metric, value FROM insights WHERE metric IN 
    ('application_widget_comments_views', 
     'application_widget_comments_views_unique', 
     'application_widget_comments_views_login', 
     'application_widget_comments_views_login_unique', 
     'application_widget_comments_views_logout') 
   AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-08-01') 
   AND period=period('day') 
   AND object_id='10151074438279445'
```

Access token was obtained as an **app access token** - Does this mean I don't need `read_insights` permission?

However I always get back an empty data array. To access insights plugin and domain metrics, what should `object_id` be?

Fetching data from `comment`, `link_stat` tables are working just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting data because the id you are passing is for a url (a Yahoo Finance url). It seems that `application_widget_comments_views...` only return data when the `object_id` is the ID for an app.

Looking through the `insights` table, it does not appear that there are any ways to get insights for a url other than via the `url_like` table.

If you've got Facebook comments on a url, you'll need to have the id of the app used to publish the comments *and* be an admin of the app.